# Left Side Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I took this screenshot from Google Plus application from Android. I would like to know

1) how can I implement this way of side navigation bar ?

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial about `navigation drawer`..http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 7):

That side navigation bar is called a `Navigation Drawer`

Information and examples are available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)